# Problem installing Steam on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, steam

I had a problem while trying to install Steam. The download completed successfully, but then I got this error:

```
[2018-10-23 16:30:25] uninstalled manifest found in 
/home/mawime/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2018-10-23 16:30:25] Extracting package...
[2018-10-23 16:30:39] Installing update...
[2018-10-23 16:30:41] Cleaning up...
[2018-10-23 16:30:41] Update complete, launching...
[2018-10-23 16:30:41] Shutdown
tar: This does not look like a "tar" type archive
xz: (stdin): Unknown file format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: `` /home/mawime/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime'':
  No such file or folder
```

Comment: How do you install steam?